# Glassfish server throwing exception when sending JSONObject through android

Tags: android, json, vaadin

when i am sending json object through android the server is throwing `NullPointerException`. The description is as such :
The device takes picture and converts it into Byte array using `Base64.java` and then to String. This string is then putted in `JSONObject` and send to the server. But server is throwing `NullPointerException`. My Server application is written in `vaadin`.

Following is the code in android for converting image to `Byte[]`:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, baos);
**byte[] ba = baos.toByteArray();
String bal = Base64.encodeBytes(ba);**
```

Code for sending `JSONObject` to server :

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
try {
    jsonObject.putOpt("imageName", imageNm);
    jsonObject.put("imageSend", bal);
} catch (JSONException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

serverUrl = serverUrl+"UploadImage" ;
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(serverUrl);
HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
try {           
    StringEntity entity=new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
    entity.setContentType("application/json;char-set=UTF-8");
    entity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json;char-set=UTF-8"));
    post.setEntity(entity);
    httpResponse = client.execute(post);
    response = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The exception on server

```
         [#|2012-12-18       T12:49:43.692+0530|INFO|glassfish         v3.0|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=40;   _ThreadName=Thread-1;|Image name : null|#]

[#|2012-12-18T12:49:43.692+0530|SEVERE|glassfishv3.0|com.vaadin.Application|_ThreadID=40;   _ThreadName=Thread-1;|Terminal error:
 java.lang.NullPointerException
         at java.io.StringReader.<init>(StringReader.java:50)
       at org.json.JSONTokener.<init>(JSONTokener.java:83)
       at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:310)
        at handlers.SPTURIHandler.handleURI(SPTURIHandler.java:91)
         at com.vaadin.ui.Window.handleURI(Window.java:424)
         at        com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleURI(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:2274)
         at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.CommunicationManager.handleURI(CommunicationManager.java:348)
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.handleURI(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:1093)
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:535)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:233)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

|#]

Is ther any thing wrong with the code...

Comment: Are you sure that the server code works? Have you tested? Because maybe the problem is on the server side and you should post the code ...

Comment: Use a servlet filter or a valve to see what content the http traffic actually contains (or use a network sniffer like wireshark instead).

Comment: Also I see that you use vaadin. Can you use it from within a native android app? Doesn't vaadin need some kind of state (component state and so on)?